# Problem with natural logarithmic function in fixed point notation

Tags: audio, c, math, fixed-point

I am facing a problem with natural logarithmic function in fixed-point notation.

Let's say

$$x = 0.54, \qquad\text{then}\qquad \ln(x) = -0.616186, \qquad\text{a negative number}  \tag{1}$$

Then in fixed-point notation, the value of $x$ is calculated by (assuming $x$ is $\rm Q8.24$ format)

```
temp_var = 0.54 * 16777216 = 9059696 (fixed point value in Q8.24 format)
```

So,

$$x = \ln(\textrm{temp_var}) = 16.01\qquad\text{since}\qquad 2^{24} = 16777216$$

And the float (true / unscaled form) value corrosponds to

$$16.01 / 16777216 = 9.54e-7\qquad\text{a positive value}\tag{2}$$

As we can see, both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are different in both magnitude and sign.

So, I just want to know how to solve these kinds of problems at a fixed point?

Comment: The log rule is ln(a*b)= ln(a) + ln(b). And x = ln(0.54 * 16777216) =16.01 not ln(16.01)

Comment: @Irreducible..I have corrected the mistake

Comment: @rkc um, why are you dividing your logarithm value... that's not how logarithms work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi, I am dividing by 16777216, just to get the true and original value of x (unscaled form). The fixed-point representation of x is 16 (8.24 format). So, the true value corresponds to (float)16 / 16777216, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have made my Question a bit more clear. Please check once.

Comment: @rkc "right?": no, not right. By linearly scaling the input, you need to add a constant negative offset to the output. this is a logarithm, not a linear operation.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi, thanks for the explanation. How do we calculate a constant negative offset value? Is it possible for you to explain this in detail?

Comment: by applying 10th class math knowledge. It's a logarithm.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Hi, I am not able to understand how to calculate the constant negative value, still. I might be missing some basics. Can you explain how to calculate the offset value?

Comment: please read the first comment again, the logarithmus rule is: log(a*b) = log(a) + log(b), that is why your division makes no sense, that is not how logarithmus works.

Comment: @Irreducible Hi, as far as I understand, you are telling that division operation shouldn't be done as I did.  I performed division in the following manner. i.e. (the result of log function) / Some integer value. If this is not the way to calculate the true value of x, how do we need to compute the true (unscaled) value? I am sorry if I miss very fundamentals. Please correct me.

Comment: once again: log(x*y)=log(x)+ log(y) => log(x) = log(x*y) -log(y) = 16.01-log(16777216)

Comment: @Irreducible In fixed-point notation, the value of x is given by (x * y), where y is the scaling factor. So, I just want to know why you are considering the "x" alone even in fixed-point notation (since you are calculating log(x))? Also, I don't know why you are calculating log(x)?

Comment: It seems I dont understand your question, what is it what you really want to achieve?